# How do I fix the saving issue I have with bitmap images?

Tags: .net, vb.net

I am currently in my last year of high school in Australia and I need some help with my final project. Long story short I am doing a cryptography program that hides the binary data of a picture within another picture (sounds intense but not really). I have gotten the data to hide within the photograph however when I save the photo and try and get the data out its not there. Do you know what I am doing wrong?

my code:

```
        pixelhColor = Seenbitmap.GetPixel(1, 1) 'Should return (255,3,0,0) with my test data and does


        PictureBoxHidden.Image = Nothing

        Nameoforigfile = Nameoforigfile.Substring(0, Nameoforigfile.Length-4)
        Seenbitmap.Save(Nameoforigfile & " With Photo.bmp")
        MessageBox.Show("The photo has been saved and your photo is encoded within.")
        PBSfile.Image = PBS
```

So, as far as I can tell, that is all well and good however when I try to get the data out I use the photo that was saved there and the data for that pixel is returned as (255,0,0,0) using getpixel(). As far as I can figure out there is an issue with saving the file. If that is not the case then I have no clue what the matter would be. Do you know what is happening?

Comment: Use a hex editor to look at the file contents to narrow down the error. Note, using camel case on identifiers makes them easier to read: `Nameoforigfile` -> `NameOfOriginalFile`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suspect that your issue is that original image's raw format is using a irreversible compression algorithm and that format is the one used when you use the `Save` method that just takes a file name.

`Seenbitmap.Save(Nameoforigfile & " With Photo.bmp")`

Try saving your altered image as a bitmap.

`Seenbitmap.Save(Nameoforigfile & " With Photo.bmp", System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Bmp)`